# ThinkingSphinx Order via URL Params

Tags: ruby, url, sorting, thinking-sphinx

I am using ThinkingSphinx in an application and right now I am not doing any type of order on my results. However, I would like to make this an option via a link someone can click on the page and it just passes it through the URL to 'refresh' the page with the results now ordered.

In the .search parameters I tried doing `:order => params[:o]` then in the URL passing `o=columnname` but that does not seem to work.

Just to note, when I hard-code the ordering it works fine, I'm not having trouble with indexing/making a DB column sortable. I would just like to make it so via a URL argument it the results can be displayed ordered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [Sphinx documentation](http://freelancing-god.github.com/ts/en/indexing.html), the fields you want to use for sorting must be flagged as sortable. Attributes defined with `has` do not have to be flagged, because all attributes are sortable:

```
class Article
  ..
  define_index do
    indexes title, :sortable => true
    indexes author(:name), :as => :author, :sortable => true
    ..
  end
```

Then one can use the `:order` and `:sort_mode` parameter to define the sort order:

```
sort_order = params[:o]
Article.search "pancakes", :order => sort_order, :sort_mode => :desc
```